# Ternary Operators. Possible for a one sided action?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I've used ternary operators for a while and was wondering if there was a method to let say call a function without the `else` clause. Example:

```
if (isset($foo)) {
    callFunction();
} else {

}
```

Now obviously we can leave out the `else` to make:

```
if (isset($foo)) {
    callFunction();
}
```

Now for a ternary How can you 'by pass' the else clause if the condition returns false?

```
isset($foo) ? callFunction() : 'do nothing!!';
```

Either a mystery or not possible?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Short-circuit

```
isset($foo) and callFunction();
```

Reverse the condition and omit the second argument

```
!isset($foo) ?: callFunction();
```

or return just "something"

```
isset($foo) ? callFunction() : null;
```

However, the ternary operators is designed to conditionally fetch a value out of two possible values. You are calling a function, thus it seems you are really looking for `if` and misuse `?:` to save characters?

```
if (isset($foo)) callFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a ternary operator in this case? The ternary operator is meant to be used when there are two possible scenarios and doesn't make much sense in the case where you only care about the `if` case. If you **have to** do it however, simply leave the case empty: `(cond)?do_something():;`

Comment: Well the above is an example. I was just wondering for bigger operations.

Comment: @Beneto Bigger operations? It really seems, that you misuse the ternary operator :X

Comment: You can't simply leave the else case empty in ternary operator ... you need to at least give it an empty value like '' or null, you can only leave out the "if true" part like `!cond?:do_something()` but not the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

Put zero after colon. Also, assuming you're on Perl, you may use better 'condition and action()', 'action() if condition' idioms.

Comment: Regarding the tags he uses PHP ;) however, the short-cicruiting of expression works in PHP too `$condition and action();`, but not the other notation. Here you can at least omit the braces, but thats all `if ($condition) action();`